# append or prepend to terraform variable v12

Tags: syntax, terraform

I read that v12 no longer requires interpolation syntax and I'd prefer to not use it whenever possible. One question I have is how do you prepend or append a string to a variable, such as for naming conventions?

with interpolation, you could

```
name = "${var.variable_name}-vnet"
```

new v12 syntax supposed to allow variables written like this, but i can't just add on a -vnet as above

```
name = var.variable_name
```

Comment: It's still the first way with interpolation. The change in HCL 2 that was introduced in 0.12 was to add first class expressions as mentioned in https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-preview-first-class-expressions/. But if you want to interpolate something like this then you still need that same syntax. Or use the `format` function as an alternative I guess but that was also available in 0.11 and below.

Comment: So you're saying you still have to wrap the variable in ${} to prepend/append a string to it? @ydaetskcoR

Answer (score 0):

The intent of the change in Terraform 0.12 was to avoid the need for *redundant* interpolation syntax and in particular to avoid the confusion implied by "interpolating" something that isn't a string in order to assign a variable's value to an argument, not to remove the interpolation syntax altogether. If your goal is to concatenate two strings together then interpolation syntax is still likely to be the most concise way to do it, because string concatenation is what the interpolation syntax is *for*.

There are some other alternatives via built-in functions but it's debatable whether each of them are more or less readable than the interpolation approach:

```
name = join("-", [var.variable_name, "vnet"])
```

```
name = format("%s-vnet", var.variable_name)
```